# find region in time with the largest successive number of values greater than one

Tags: matlab, find

I have two time series:

```
dat = [0,2,3,0,2,2,0,0,1,0.8,3,4,6,7,4,4,3,0,1,3,2.2,0];
dat2 = dat+.5;
time = 1:length(dat);
plot(time,dat);
hold on;
plot(time,dat2,'r');
```

I would like to find the region in time that both vectors have the greatest successive number of values greater than one. So, for this particular example, both vectors have values greater than 1 between 10 and 18. However, they also have values greater than one on several other occasions. I can obtain the indices of the values greater than one by first generating a matrix:

```
data = [dat',dat2'];
```

And then using find

```
r1 = data>1;
```

This will provide me with the location of each value that is greater than one. Next I would like to find at what time (between which rows) are the values > 1 maintained for the longest duration. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can test `rBoth = dat>1 & dat2>1` for both being above on at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the indices of the longest run of values, you can use the following code:

```
dat = [0,2,3,0,2,2,0,0,1,0.8,3,4,6,7,4,4,3,0,1,3,2.2,0];

id = find(dat>1);
x = [0 cumsum(diff(id)~=1)];

id(x==mode(x))
```

This results in

```
ans =

    11    12    13    14    15    16    17
```

This code can be used with a matrix:

```
dat = [0,2,3,0,2,2,0,0,1,0.8,3,4,6,7,4,4,3,0,1,3,2.2,0];
dat2 = dat+.5;
data = [dat',dat2'];

id = find(all(data>1, 2));
x = [0; cumsum(diff(id(:))~=1)];

id(x==mode(x))
```

This code gives the indices of the longest run of values greater than one in both columns:

```
ans =
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
```

Comment: you have peaked my interest in matlab

Comment: @LastCoder: If you know your way around Matlab a bit, typing times (and thus development times - every character is a potential bug) go down so much.

Comment: I am assuming that y is 'dat'?

Comment: @Kate No, it's `id`. Sorry that was a typo. I fixed in the answer.

Comment: So, does this still work for a matrix? My example was a matrix and this is a vector?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use matlab, but the below should get you the max range for one vector at least.

```
rangeStart = 0;
rangeEnd = 0;
rangeLength = 0;
for i = 1:length(dat)
    for j = i+1:length(dat)
        % skip ranges smaller than the max
        if ((j-i)+1) <= rangeLength
            continue
        end
        % check to see if the range (i,j) meets the condition
        good = true;
        for x = i:j
            if dat(x) <= 1
                good = false;
            end
        end
        % the range meets the condition record the results
        if good
            rangeStart = i;
            rangeEnd = j;
            rangeLength = ((j-i)+1);
        end
    end
end
```

If you want to find the maximum range shared between both vectors you'd change

```
            if dat(x) <= 1
```

to

```
            if dat(x) <= 1 || dat2(x) <= 1
```

Barring any syntax errors the above should do the trick, there is likely a fancier (read more efficient) matlab specific solution.